# not able login to aws ecr from jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecr

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'label'
    }

     environment {
         AWS_ACCESS_ID = credentials('aws-access-key')
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = credentials('aws-secret-key')

    DKR_AWS_CLI = 'docker run ' +
      '-e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_ID} ' +
      '-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY} ' +
      '-e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1 ' +
      //'-v `pwd`:/project ' +
      'image1/aws-cli'

}

  stages {

stage('pull latest aws-cli docker image') {

            steps {

                sh "docker pull image1/aws-cli"
            }
        }
        stage('logging in to AWS ECR') {

            steps {

                script {

                    def ECR_LOGIN = sh(
                            script: "${DKR_AWS_CLI} ecr get-login --region=eu-central-1",
                            returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                    sh "${ECR_LOGIN}"
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

I have added my credentials to jenkins and i am not able to login to ECR getting the below error

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9a816fa0d0>, 'Connection to ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

Comment: We are using proxy in our organization and the proxy is already declared in environment section

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly you also need to programatically(i.e., in your code) add a token for your session.

Comment: didn't got your answer , can you please elaborate it

Comment: usually you get an access Token to use for the duration of the session which in your example do not set in the same way you set Access Key and Secret Access key, I cant guarantee that it is needed though, you can check [ECR credential helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper)

Answer (score 0):

You can write Jenkins pipeline as above. You can store ecr credentials in Jenkins and refer Jenkins credentials in the pipeline. In this example code, I have referred to it as `ecr-credentials`.
Make sure your IAM user has permission to access ECR.

```
pipeline {
        
        environment {
          registry = "xxxx.xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo"
          dockerImage = ''
        }
      
      
        stages {
          
          stage('Create Docker image') {
              
              steps {
                  
                  script {
                      dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
                  }
              }
          }
          
          stage('Push Docker image to Docker Registry') {
              steps {
                  script {
                      docker.withRegistry( "https://" + registry, "ecr:aws-region:ecr-credentials") {
                      dockerImage.push()
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          
      
        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stage('Login ECR image') {
              
              steps {
                  
                  script {
                      sh "aws ecr get-login-password --region ADD_YOUR_REGION_NAME | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ADD_YOUR_REPO_NAME"
                      sh "docker build -t image_name_containing_repo_name ."
                      sh "docker push image_name_containing_repo_name"
                  }
              }
          }
```

repo name starts with `AWS_ACCOUNT_NO.dkr.ecr.YOUR_REGION_NAME.amazonaws.com` in the login command